Salesforce flow How to start a collection at number 10?
I am using a flow in salesforce to return cases, now I want to show the cases in a einstein bot, it has a limitazation of 10 records at the momento to display by the screen, so I was thinking about using pagnitation for those records.
What I do not know, how to statrt the loop or the collection of cases at 10th, so next time que query retunrs those next 10 items


Have an i variable with 0 (zero) as default value.
Have a Loop action
The Loop action has Decision action. The Decision check if i equals or more than 10.
If yes -> do the bot thing
If no -> increase i variable by 1.

If you will need batches of 10 records - use formula for the Decision action.
